# Redirect("/Error/UnAuthorized") not working in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

Could anyone please help me why the following code not working? The redirect doesn't occur while debugging:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);

    Redirect("/Error/UnAuthorized");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following should work:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    var url = Url.Action("UnAuthorized", "Error");
    requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

This being said, you should not be doing any redirects in the `Initialize` method. Personally I've never had to override this method. And even worse, it seems that you are handling authorization in this method which is bad. I would strongly recommend you using a custom Authorize attribute for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks @Darin I get this error when I copy paste your code "Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent"

Comment: @Darin, basically I'm got ApplicationController : Controller and I'm checking the specific cookie value. If no cookie then show access denied to users.

Comment: @flybyte, don't do this in the Initialize method. Write a custom Authorize attribute for this purpose.

Comment: any reason why 
    Redirect("/Error/UnAuthorized");  doesnt work?

Comment: @flybyte, as I said in my answer you should avoid doing redirects in the `Initialize` method.

Comment: hm...ok. The reason I'm doing this on Initialize is that i've got some dynamic (from db) footer data that  needs to be shown once the user logs in. Only way I know of passing data to master page is via base ApplicationController Class. At the same time i needed to check if browser have appropriate cookies to authenticate browser level.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC you should return a redirect result, rather than using Response.Redirect.

Also, I'd say with the error you're getting (headers sent), you're processing this too late in the request.

Here's an example of redirecting from an action method.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Basecamp()
{
    if (!GetPlanPolicyForUser().IntegrationEnabled)
    {
        Log<ApplicationsController>.Action( "..." );
        return Redirect("/applications/notsupported");
    }
    //...
}
```